# Why does do_action pass a blank string as the first parameter if no $arg is set?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

I'm having a hard time understanding how to set up a function with a default parameter and then call it with the `do_action` in WordPress. I'm not sure if this is a WordPress issue or just me not understanding the `do_action` method. What happens is I define a function like this:

```
function contact_info( $show_logo=true ) {

    var_dump( $show_logo );    
}
```

Then I add the hook like this:

```
add_action( 'show_contact_info', 'contact_info' );
```

Finally when I call the do_action like this:

```
do_action('show_contact_info');
```

I would expect a the `var_dump` to be `bool(true)`, but what I am getting is: `string(0) ""`

So my question is WHY?

It doesn't seem to be accepting the default as set in my function, or more specifically, the `do_action` call ALWAYS seems to pass blank as the first parameter if one is not defined in the call. Is this standard for Wordpress? Why would it not pass NULL?

Comment: In addition to the answer birgire's answer, you can use `add_action( 'show_contact_info', 'contact_info', 10, 0 );` to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

When we fire up:

```
do_action( 'foo' );
```

we are actually calling:

```
do_action( 'foo', '' );
```

That's because how it's [defined](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/); With **the empty string as the default input argument**:

```
function do_action($tag, $arg = '') {
    // ...
}
```

So the action's callback get's the empty string as it's first input argument.

This has been like this since at least WordPress [version 1.5](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/1.5-branch/wp-includes/functions.php#L970).

Since WordPress 4.6, `do_action()` is a wrapper of [`WP_Hook::do_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_hook/);

*What if ...*

It looks like if it would be defined without the argument part as:

```
function do_action($tag) {
    // ...
}
```

and with corresponding modifications to this part:

```
$args = array();
if ( is_array($arg) && 1 == count($arg) && isset($arg[0]) && is_object($arg[0]) ) // array(&$this)
    $args[] =& $arg[0];
else
    $args[] = $arg;
```

then we might use the default value, of the first input argument,  in our callback.

Comment: Check out https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14881 for some more information on this.

Comment: thanks for the trac link @swissspidy  Hopefully this will be resolved some day.

Comment: I was just wondering about a possible patch for this, when writing the answer, but it looks like @nacin has already patched it 7 years ago [here in #14881.diff](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/14881/14881.diff) ;-)